# MediaRecorder.setVideSize occurs start failed: -19

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

Below code run successfully on many devices (even on Samsung Galaxy Note3) but it does not run on Samsung Galaxy Note 4, I start preview then if user press save button below method run.
If i delete setVideSize line eveything works fine in Note 4 but if i add it, screen stacks .

Thank you for your concern.

```
try {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<Camera.Size> sizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes();
    mCamera.unlock();
    if(mediaRecorder == null)
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.getHolder().getSurface());
    if (mCameraId != CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);

    }

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    Log.e("W = ",""+sizes.get(0).width);
    Log.e("H = ",""+sizes.get(0).height);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(sizes.get(0).width, sizes.get(0).height);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(2000000);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        relaseCamera();
        return false;

    }
    return true;
```

**SOLUTION**

```
try {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    mCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();    
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280,720);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(2000000);
    if(mediaRecorder == null)
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.getHolder().getSurface());
    if (mCameraId != CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);

    }


    try {

        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        relaseCamera();
        return false;

    }
    return true;
```

Comment: If anyone guides me, i guess he/she will go heaven

Comment: ok, no one did not respond and at last i found the problem. I will be alone in heaven. Problem was related with setting parameters of mediarecorder. I added above the solution.

Comment: Hi. What was the problem?

Comment: I cannot see what you did with setVideoSize to solve the problem. Please show me!